# Toggle animate division height on image click (hide by default?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have been searching on the internet but no good solution found so far. On my HTML page there is a *#menu-button* inside my fixed *#header* division and a *#menu-panel* division below this header. The menu panel toggle-collapses by clicking on the button image. The code below works great, except that the animated *#menu-panel* is visible by default.

Does anyone know how to make the division height 0 by default, but still toggle animate height when clicking the button? Code below:

```
<body>

<div id="header">
  <img src="image" id="menu-button">
</div>

<div id="menu-panel">
  <ul>
    <li>some buttons listed here</li>
    <li>some buttons listed here</li>
    <li>some buttons listed here</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
// header menu
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu-button").click(function(){
  $("#menu-panel").animate({
  height: 'toggle'
  });
  });
  });
</script>

</body>
```

Thank you in advance!

Elmigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" The code below works great, except that the animated #menu-panel is visible by default."

Change this: `<div id="menu-panel">`
on `<div id="menu-panel" style="display:none">`